# Displaying linq query result in label

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext

I tried to display result linq query display in textbox. I have OID, readTime, DeviceID, a_TankLevel1, a_TankLevel2 in SensorDataPackages table. I want to display value of some field in a textbox after query returns like this

```
Textbox1 = a_TankLevel1;
Textbox2 = a_TankLevel2;
```

an so forth.

I get "SensorData is not empty".Query is working.

//I created new modeldataset

```
private string istDeviceID = "";

  MyWebApplication.MyClasses.ModelDataContext MyNewModel= new MyWebApplication.MyClasses.ModelDataContext();  

        this.istDeviceID = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue("DeviceID").ToString();

        DateTime SensorDateNow= DateTime.Now;
        DateTime SensorDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

        var SensorData = (from Sensor in MyNewModel.SensorDataPackages
        where Sensor.DeviceID == int.Parse(istDeviceID)
        where Sensor.readTime.Date >= SensorDateNow.Date
        where Sensor.readTime.Date <= SensorDate.Date
        select Sensor).ToList();                

       if (SensorData.Count > 0)          
       {
           MessageBox.Show("SensorData is not empty");              
           textbox1.text = SensorData.?????? // I need help here !!!
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("SensorData is empty");
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
textbox1.text= String.Join(",", SensorData.Select(a => a.ToString()));
```

This is assuming that your SensorData object has an overridden `ToString()`

EDIT:

The get the last value try this

```
textbox1.text= SensorData.Last().a_TankLevel1.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried textbox1.text= String.Join(",", SensorData.Select(a => a.ToString());  and textbox1.text=String.Join(",",SensorData.Select(a=>a.a_TankLevel1.ToString()));   but textbot is empty.

Comment: can you post what is in the `ToString` for `SensorData`

Comment: Textbox1.Text=SensorData.ToString(); result :  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyWebApplication.MyClasess.SensorDataPackage]

Comment: Have you overridden the `ToString` in your class?

Comment: I dont have override tostring in my class

Comment: Why not try to change .ToString() with the method name/property you want to show in the TextBox?

Comment: What is it that you want shown in the textbox, can you give an example?

Comment: @DavidPilkington I want to display value of a_TankLevel1 in textbox1. Textbox1=12344 etc.

Comment: @DavidPilkington I can display all result of query in a gridview.But I dont know how to display one field in label ?

Comment: Assign the string.Join to a variable and put a breakpoint on it. then when it hits the break point, hover over it and see what the value is

Comment: @DavidPilkington when I used breakpoint http://snag.gy/Xl2iP.jpg and http://snag.gy/U2Okv.jpg

Comment: @DavidPilkington when I use  lblTankSeviye2.Text = String.Join(",", SensorData.Select(a => a.a_TankLevel1.ToString()));
result : http://snag.gy/8Uv22.jpg   but I want label : 65. 65 is value of the last time in a_Tank1Level

Comment: Ah okj, so you want the last value then?

Comment: I want to display last value (in query it is first record) in a label!   Label1=65,65,65,65,67,68,69,70(it takes all a_Tank1Level values) but I want it to be Label1 :65